# What are the possible errors thrown by fs readFileSync method?

Tags: node.js

I've been pouring over the documentation and I understand it is difficult to document all possible errors thrown by various elements. I struggle to document the errors thrown in my own APIs. But it doesn't change the fact that being able to know what errors can be thrown by, say, any given method would be *very* convenient. Hoping someone else may have been down this road before and can provide a list or link. In this case I'm particularly interested in what can be thrown from calling [fs.readFileSync()](https://nodejs.org/docs/latest-v12.x/api/fs.html#fs_fs_readfilesync_path_options)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To figure this out, look at the [source code](https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/master/lib/fs.js) for `readFileSync`. It is, in full:

```
function readFileSync(path, options) {
  options = getOptions(options, { flag: 'r' });
  const isUserFd = isFd(path); // File descriptor ownership
  const fd = isUserFd ? path : fs.openSync(path, options.flag, 0o666);

  const stats = tryStatSync(fd, isUserFd);
  const size = isFileType(stats, S_IFREG) ? stats[8] : 0;
  let pos = 0;
  let buffer; // Single buffer with file data
  let buffers; // List for when size is unknown

  if (size === 0) {
    buffers = [];
  } else {
    buffer = tryCreateBuffer(size, fd, isUserFd);
  }

  let bytesRead;

  if (size !== 0) {
    do {
      bytesRead = tryReadSync(fd, isUserFd, buffer, pos, size - pos);
      pos += bytesRead;
    } while (bytesRead !== 0 && pos < size);
  } else {
    do {
      // The kernel lies about many files.
      // Go ahead and try to read some bytes.
      buffer = Buffer.allocUnsafe(8192);
      bytesRead = tryReadSync(fd, isUserFd, buffer, 0, 8192);
      if (bytesRead !== 0) {
        ArrayPrototypePush(buffers, buffer.slice(0, bytesRead));
      }
      pos += bytesRead;
    } while (bytesRead !== 0);
  }

  if (!isUserFd)
    fs.closeSync(fd);

  if (size === 0) {
    // Data was collected into the buffers list.
    buffer = Buffer.concat(buffers, pos);
  } else if (pos < size) {
    buffer = buffer.slice(0, pos);
  }

  if (options.encoding) buffer = buffer.toString(options.encoding);
  return buffer;
}
```

`getOptions` [can throw](https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/master/lib/internal/fs/utils.js) a `ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE` exception if the `options` parameter is not of the right type.

The call to `fs.openSync` will result in [`validatePath`](https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/master/lib/internal/fs/utils.js) being called, which can also throw a `ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE` error, or, through `nullCheck` (in `utils.js`), `ERR_INVALID_ARG_VALUE`.

`tryCreateBuffer` can throw `ERR_FS_FILE_TOO_LARGE`.

And so on. Getting a list of all possible errors will be a slog - you'll have to go through all the possible function calls recursively - but it's doable.

Comment: agreed, a slog ( maybe it could be automated to create an appendix to nodejs documentation ) but doable ... and worth it! i'd add ... thanks :)